# Matching the width of a table column to text in a fixed width table (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, html-table, formatting

I have a table of log entries that I want to display with two columns: the timestamp, and the log entry itself.  The table has a fixed width.  I want the timestamp column to stretch to fit the text of the timestamp itself and go no further, then let the rest of the table's width be taken up by the message.  I want the timestamp text to always be one line and let the log message wrap around.  I have that part working, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make the column width fit the text width of the timestamp.  I can do a fixed pixel width, but that seems iffy for this.

EDIT: Updated with code example: (http://jsfiddle.net/GH7jj/7/)

```
<div class="MainDiv">
<table class="LogTableStyle">
<tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Message</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="LogTime">11/07/2012 07:38:14</td>
    <td class="LogMessage">There was something that happened at this point.  This is a pretty long message though.  It should be wrapping around.  I want the timestamp to be on that one line while giving this message as much room as possible.  That'd be cool.</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
.MainDiv {
    min-width:300px;
    max-width:500px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#F0F0FF;
    margin:auto;
}
.LogTableStyle {
    width:97%;
    margin:auto;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.LogTableStyle th {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    padding:3px;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
}
.LogTableStyle td {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
}
.LogTime {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.LogMessage {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}​
```

Comment: Try setting `white-space: nowrap` on the timestamp column and let the browser size the columns.

Comment: example code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar would help too.

Comment: When I do that it cuts them 50/50.  I want to shrink the first and let the second fill the rest.

Comment: Removing the width property of the table itself seems to get the behavior I want, but then the table just explodes into other things on the page.  I need the table to max out in a div without overflowing.

Comment: Getting closer.  http://jsfiddle.net/GH7jj/8/  When there's an enormous chunk of text it overflows, but otherwise it's behaving as expected.  If I set the overflow to hidden, the words won't wrap as the table column width is just enormous again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* http://jsfiddle.net/oatkiller/GH7jj/9/ */

.LogTableStyle {
    width:97%;
    margin:auto;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

I just removed table-layout: fixed from your CSS. Is this what you intended to do?

Quotes from w3schools:

auto
Automatic table layout algorithm (this is default):
The column width is set by the widest unbreakable content in the cells
Can be slow, since it needs to read through all the content in the table, before determining the final layout

fixed
Fixed table layout algorithm:
The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells
Allows a browser to lay out the table faster than the automatic table layout
The browser can begin to display the table once the first row has been received

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

Comment: Very close!  Now there's one hitch left: http://jsfiddle.net/GH7jj/10/

Can this be wrangled into behaving?  It can cut off the too-long strings into ellipsis but it can't explode over the div.  I can set overflow to hidden but then the wrapping on the other entries gets hidden too.

Comment: There's the [word-wrap: break-word;](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap), but somehow it didn't work. However, [putting the long message in a small div](http://jsfiddle.net/GH7jj/12/) sorta work (in FF, at least)...

Comment: Kraz, that gave me an idea... http://jsfiddle.net/GH7jj/13/ The div isn't needed.  I can just add the style to selected entries.  Since I'm building the table dynamically I can add that class to any entry that has a word that's unreasonably long.  I'll have to fiddle with just how I decide that, but I think this'll do it!  Thanks all!

Comment: Update: perfect!  I'm checking for any 20+ character chunks of text and sticking on the word break style to that entry if anything's found.  Between that and robert's catch, it's working just as I want it to.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/oatkiller/GH7jj/14/ I added word-break: break-word to the log message div.

Comment: That's definitely cleaner than the solution I ended up on, but is that supported everywhere?  I'm getting a syntax error and I'm not seeing that as a valid property, but it seems to work in chrome at least...

Comment: Tried it on IE and it broke. :(

Comment: It's not supported everywhere. I do know that PHP for example has a word wrap function built in for handling this in the backend.